# AngularJS - Find all ngModel in the current scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a HTML template like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="model.name" /> {{model.addr}}
    <button ng-click="detect()">detect</button>
</div>
```

And this is the controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.detect = function() {
        var fields = []; //['model.name', 'model.addr']
        //call server with selected fields
    }
}
```

The template can be customized by user and generated dynamically, not static template. I want to optimize the data model returned from server, only return values for needed fields in the template. The idea is I want to get all the ng-model fields from template and pass them to the server. The returned data will contain only values for these fields, instead of whole data model, for example:

```
{
    name: 'Superhero',
    addr: 'Mars'
}
```

If I change the template like this (remove model.addr):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="model.name" />
    <button ng-click="detect()">detect</button>
</div>
```

The fields array should be `['model.name']` and the returned data from the server should be:

```
{
    name: 'Superhero'
}
```

There are any ways to get all ng-model fields in the scope?
Thanks!

Comment: In angular the model and the data should map or lets say should be connected. You cant select elements by tags such as in jQuery. Even if you do this with jQuery it would be incorrect angular and would lead to others difficulties such as models not updating later on. Are you building a form builder?

Comment: @astro yes, I'm building a form builder.

Comment: okay then what you need to do is treat each of your forms as a directive and parse the form builder's input object you got from the server on to the directive and update the modal you're submitting accordingly. take a look at this project how he's done it  https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form and https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms   it's kinda hard to explain on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can do 1 thing, wherever you are using ng-modal, take an object modal and assign values by using dot(.).

Suppose

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input ng-model="model.name1" />
<input ng-model="model.name2" />
<input ng-model="model.name3" />  
<button ng-click="detect()">detect</button>
```

So you can get model in scope hence all the attributes of scope.